# separate texts into sentences NLTK vs spaCy

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy, sentence

I want to separate texts into sentences.

looking in stack overflow I found:

WITH NLTK

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
text="""Hello Mr. Smith, how are you doing today? The weathe is great, and city is awesome. The sky is pinkish-blue. You shouldn't eat cardboard"""
tokenized_text=sent_tokenize(text)
print(tokenized_text)
```

WITH SPACY

```
from spacy.lang.en import English # updated

raw_text = 'Hello, world. Here are two sentences.'
nlp = English()
nlp.add_pipe(nlp.create_pipe('sentencizer')) # updated
doc = nlp(raw_text)
sentences = [sent.string.strip() for sent in doc.sents]
```

The question is what in the background for spacy having to do it differently with a so called create_pipe.
Sentences are important for training your own word embedings for NLP. There should be a reason why spaCy does not include directly out of the box a sentence tokenizer.

Thanks.

NOTE: Be aware that a simply .split(.) does not work, there are several decimal numbers in the text and other kind of tokens containing '.'

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. Keep in mind that spaCy is a simple framework for easy NLP for begginers or generalist practitioners in first place. It can be customized, but by default you have to do some tweaks if you and a more specialized solution - you can even train models for it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, spaCy uses its dependency parser to do sentence segmentation, which requires loading a statistical model.
The [`sentencizer`](https://spacy.io/api/sentencizer) is a rule-based sentence segmenter that you can use to define your own sentence segmentation rules without loading a model.

If you don't mind leaving the parser activated, you can use the following code:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm') # or whatever model you have installed
raw_text = 'Hello, world. Here are two sentences.'
doc = nlp(raw_text)
sentences = [sent.text.strip() for sent in doc.sents]
```

Answer (score 0):

The processing pipeline in `spaCy` has a modular setup, more information is given here: https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines. You define which parts you want by defining the pipes. There are some use-cases where potentially you don't need sentences, like when you only want a bag-of-words representation. So I guess that may be why the `sentencizer` is not always included automatically - but it's there if you need it.

Note that `English()` is a pretty generic model - you can find some more useful pre-trained statistical models here: https://spacy.io/models/en

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7961860/sofie-vlt :  hallo @Sofie VL, is it possible to see the sentence splitter spacy code in order to add in more rules?